# Cartopy: Can't add features to geo axes (no errors or warnings)

Tags: python, plot, rendering, cartopy

I can't add features to cartopy geo axes. Here is an example from the [gallery](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/features.html):

```
import cartopy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():

    ax = plt.axes(projection=cartopy.crs.PlateCarree())

    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.COASTLINE)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle=':')
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAKES, alpha=0.5)
    ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.RIVERS)

    ax.set_extent([-20, 60, -40, 40])

    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this on my laptop at home I get nothing but a blank geo axes in the figure (I can tell because the extents are correct and I can see the coordinates in the bottom left hand corner of the figure window. BUT - if I run this same example at work, everything plots as expected in the link.

My feeling is that there is some kind of dependency issue, but I'm not sure where to start with this one. There are absolutely no warnings or errors of any kind.

Both at work and on my laptop I am running Windows 7 x64 with Python 2.7 and installed cartopy via windows binaries from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

If I plot something myself like a contour plot then it does show up, but I think there is something going wrong between getting the data from naturalearthddata.com, processing the shape files, and adding them to the axes.

Does anyone have any ideas on where to start with this one?

Comment: Are your matplotlib versions the same?

Comment: Actually no, the version that this code is working on is 1.3.1 and it's not working with 1.4.2... I guess I could go back to 1.3.1 and see how it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't getting this error previously, but when I ran the code from an IPython notebook for some reason I got this error `HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

What I ended up having to do was change line 264 in `shapereader.py` from:

```
 _NE_URL_TEMPLATE = ('http://www.nacis.org/naturalearth/{resolution}'
                        '/{category}/ne_{resolution}_{name}.zip')
```

To:

```
_NE_URL_TEMPLATE = ('http://www.naturalearthdata.com/'
                        'http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/{resolution}'
                        '/{category}/ne_{resolution}_{name}.zip')
```

Which was recommended in multiple places in the past including [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/scitools-iris/aawdQFPumpU/PjREeNlRZJAJ)

It has been mentioned that cartopy has since fixed this broken link to naturalearth in the latest release, but I think the link is not updated in the version of cartopy that I have installed via the mentioned windows binary. I think this issue is fairly well documented, but for some reason I could not see what the actual error was up until now.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for letting me know. Interesting that the error got swallowed on Windows.